# JQuery Ajax error - xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );

Tags: jquery

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".submit").click(function(){
                var prid=$(this).attr("id");
                $.ajax({
                    dataType:"HTML",
                    contentType:"text/html",
                    url:"details.jsp",
                    type:"get",
                    data:prid,
                    success:function(data){
                        $(".modal-body").html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

When running this Ajax script I am getting this error in Jquery.I changed the Jquery version then also I am getting this error. Anybody please help me in correcting this....

xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );

Comment: Does prid has a value, do console.log(prid) and check it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.